# Appending dictionary key/values to a list within a list?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to introduce a "parameters" list for keeping application parameters, and grow that list with a python filter as I come up with new parameters with new keys/values for a given application.

This is my current data set

Source list

```
---
main_yml_vars:
  - order_number: 0
    name: create_temp_folder
    description: Create C:\ temp folder
  - order_number: 1
    name: 7zip
    description: Install 7zip with either exe or msi
```

I'm trying to write a python filter that will create a "parameter" list and allow me to continue appending key/values to it.

E.g:

```
---
main_yml_vars:
  - order_number: 0
    name: create_temp_folder
    description: Create C:\ temp folder
  - order_number: 1
    name: 7zip
    description: Install 7zip with either exe or msi
    parameters:
      - msi_file_name: 7z2104-x64.msi
```

This is the ansible code I'm using to add 'msi_file_name' to my parameters list:

```
- name: Add the msi file name to index 1 in the list
  set_fact:
    main_yml_vars: "{{ main_yml_vars | add_item(1, 'msi_file_name', '7z2104-x64.msi') }}"
```

Here is my python filter. I supply it the main_yml_vars, and then give it which index/order number to work on, and then the details of the new parameter key/value pair I'd like to add.

Python filter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'add_item': self.add_item
        }

    def add_item(self, obj, order_number, parameter_key, parameter_value):
        result = []
        for r in obj:
            if(r['order_number'] == order_number):
            try:
                parameters
            except NameError:
                parameters = []
            else:
                parameters = r['parameters']
            new_dictionary = {parameter_key: parameter_value}
            parameters.append(new_dictionary)
            r['parameters'] = parameters
            result.append(r)
        return result
```

However, when I re-run it, id like to continue appending to "parameters," instead it overwrites it.

Using the expected list from above that already has 'msi_file_name' appended, when running the following

```
- name: Add the msi file name to the selected task
  set_fact:
    main_yml_vars: "{{ main_yml_vars | add_item(1, 'exe_file_name', '7z2104-x64.exe') }}"
```

I expect this:

```
---
main_yml_vars:
  - order_number: 0
    name: create_temp_folder
    description: Create C:\ temp folder
  - order_number: 1
    name: 7zip
    description: Install 7zip with either exe or msi
    parameters:
      - msi_file_name: 7z2104-x64.msi
      - exe_file_name: 7z2104-x64.exe
```

But I get this

```
---
main_yml_vars:
  - order_number: 0
    name: create_temp_folder
    description: Create C:\ temp folder
  - order_number: 1
    name: 7zip
    description: Install 7zip with either exe or msi
    parameters:
      - exe_file_name: 7z2104-x64.exe
```

How do I go about appending more key/values to "parameters" and growing it?

Any idea if there is an existing key (e.g. msi_file_name), to just "update" it to the new "parameter_value" rather than have two entries of the same key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter seems to be a little more complex, so one solution:
objective is to create a new dict inside parameters list when the key doesnt exist or update the value when the key exist..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'add_item': self.add_item
        }

    def add_item(self, obj, order_number, parameter_key, parameter_value):
        result = []
        for r in obj:
            if r['order_number'] == order_number:
                if 'parameters' in r:
                    if any(parameter_key in d for d in r['parameters']):
                        for d in r['parameters']:
                            d.update((k, parameter_value) for k, v in d.items() if k == parameter_key)
                    else:
                        r['parameters'].append({parameter_key: parameter_value})
                else:
                    r['parameters']=[{parameter_key: parameter_value}]

            result.append(r)   
 
        return result
```

some test:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    main_yml_vars:
      - order_number: 0
        name: create_temp_folder
        description: Create C:\ temp folder
      - order_number: 1
        name: 7zip
        description: Install 7zip with either exe or msi
        parameters:
          - msi_file_name: 7z2104-x64.msi
  tasks:

  - name: Add the msi file name to index 1 in the list
    set_fact:
      main_yml_vars: "{{ main_yml_vars | add_item(1, 'msi_file_name', '7z2105-x64.exe') }}"
  - set_fact:
      main_yml_vars: "{{ main_yml_vars | add_item(1, 'exe_file_namex', '7z2104-x64.exit') }}"
  - set_fact:
      main_yml_vars: "{{ main_yml_vars | add_item(1, 'exe_file_namexxx', '7z2104-x64.exit') }}"
  - set_fact:
      main_yml_vars: "{{ main_yml_vars | add_item(0, 'exe_file_name', '7z2104-x64.exe') }}"
  - name: display result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ main_yml_vars }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "description": "Create C:\\ temp folder",
            "name": "create_temp_folder",
            "order_number": 0,
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "exe_file_name": "7z2104-x64.exe"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Install 7zip with either exe or msi",
            "name": "7zip",
            "order_number": 1,
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "msi_file_name": "7z2105-x64.exe"
                },
                {
                    "exe_file_namex": "7z2104-x64.exit"
                },
                {
                    "exe_file_namexxx": "7z2104-x64.exit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My Hero! Working like a charm. Yes you're code is much cleaner than what I had written. Thanks so much!